# Ubuntu 16.04 not detecting 3g data card

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 is not detecting Mcromax 3g data card in network while selecting for device in mobile broadband option but it is working fine with Ubuntu 14.04, but entering lsub in Ubuntu 16.04 it shows
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1c9e:f000 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY

Comment: Have you applied all updates ? If not, try updating the packages `usb-modeswitch` and `usb-modeswitch-data`.

Comment: Usually I keep updating the os as 'sudo apt-get update', I suppose those package should get updated.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` does not actually update any packages - use the graphical update manager for that.